# Using SFINAE for structs definitions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, struct, sfinae

One often sees SFINAE used for functions. For example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<int N>//version for N!=4
typename std::enable_if<N==4, int>::type val(){
    return N;
}

template<int N>//version for N==4
typename std::enable_if<N!=4, int>::type val(){
    return 2*N;
}

int main(){
  std::cout<<val<4>()<<std::endl;//prints: 4, version N==4
  std::cout<<val<5>()<<std::endl;//prints: 10, version N==10
}
```

Can I use SNIFAE not only for functions but also for structs? Something like:

```
...
template<int N, typename std::enable_if<N==4>::type>
struct S{
    int v;//for N==4 v  should be int
    ...
};

template<int N, typename std::enable_if<N!=4>::type>
struct S{
    long v;//for N!=4 v  should be long
    ...
};
```

The compiler does not accept it, even if I don't try to instantiate.

What is the right way to use SFINAE with structs?

Or should one use a different technique in order to achieve the goal of having different struct-members for different N values?

PS: Using SFINAE for N==4 does not make much sense, please consider it to be a place holder for more complicated constrains.

**Edit:** I was not aware, that SFINAE is only for functions and not for classes. `std::conditinal` is a way out if there are only two possibilities. If there are more than two different behaviours one would like to pick from, than the answer to the [question shown by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079746/template-overloading-and-sfinae-working-only-with-functions-but-not-classes) is a possible solution.

Comment: SFINAE is about function overload resolution, so it's not clear what your question means. It looks like you just want class template specialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all you want is class template specialization:

```
template <int N> struct S
{
    long v;
    // ...
};

template <> struct S<4>
{
    int v;
    // ...
};
```

Complexity can be managed by factoring such choices into separate trait class templates and then using a dependent type such as `typename type_picker<N>::type v;`. Or you can use a ready-made picker: `typename std::conditional<N == 4, int, long>::type v;`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But what if I need different implementations for "N is even" and "N is odd" or even more complicated. Can it be also done by means of template specialization?

Comment: @ead: Yes, it can. You can specialize on some intermediate selector parameter, e.g. a boolean, like `std::conditional` does it.