# Specializing class with SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

I want to write a `template class` which checks a trait with SFINAE.

As classes can not be "overloaded" as I read in that post: [template overloading and SFINAE working only with functions but not classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079746/template-overloading-and-sfinae-working-only-with-functions-but-not-classes)

I wrote the following code:

```
class AA { public: using TRAIT = int; };
class BB { public: using TRAIT = float; };

template < typename T, typename UNUSED = void> class X;

template < typename T>
class X<T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< int, typename T::TRAIT>::value, int >::type>
{
    public:
        X() { std::cout << "First" << std::endl; }
 };

template < typename T>
class X<T, typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same< int, typename T::TRAIT>::value, unsigned int >::type>
{
    public:
        X() { std::cout << "Second" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    X<AA> a;
    X<BB> b;
}
```

But it simply fails with:

```
error: aggregate 'X<AA> a' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
         X<AA> a;
               ^

error: aggregate 'X<BB> b' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
         X<BB> b;
```

It seams that none of the templates works but I get no hint from the compiler why both specializations fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specializations have to match the primary. The lookup rule for determining what `X<AA>` is is to first match the primary and add the default types, which gets us to `X<AA, void>`, and then try to match that against all the specializations. But none of your specializations match `X<AA, void>` so you end up with the primary. The primary isn't a complete type, hence the error.

Why do none of them match? Because you wrote:

```
typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< int, typename T::TRAIT>::value, int >::type
```

For `AA` that evalutes as `int`, which doesn't match `void`, so the specialization isn't considered. You just want:

```
typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< int, typename T::TRAIT>::value>::type
```

or really:

```
std::enable_if_t< std::is_same< int, typename T::TRAIT>::value>
```

Similarly, for `BB`, the second specialization's second type evaluates as `unsigned int` instead of `void` - so it too doesn't match.