# Inheritance and explicit constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, explicit-constructor

Consider the following code :

```
template<typename T> class Base
{
    Base();
    Base(const Base<T>& rhs);
    template<typename T0> explicit Base(const Base<T0>&  rhs);
    template<typename T0, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T0>::value>::type> Base(const T0& rhs);
    explicit Base(const std::string& rhs);
};

template<typename T> class Derived : Base<T>
{
    Derived();
    Derived(const Derived<T>& rhs);
    template<class T0> Derived(const T0& rhs) : Base(rhs); 
    // Is there a way to "inherit" the explicit property ?
    // Derived(double) will call an implicit constructor of Base
    // Derived(std::string) will call an explicit constructor of Base
};
```

Is there a way to redesign this code in a such way that `Derived` will have all the constructors of `Base` with the same explicit/implicit properties ?

Comment: Inherited constructors do this. It's just a pity that they aren't yet implemented on any compiler that I know of :( I'm quite certain you can do this by hand (traits to detect implicit/explicity constructibility can be written easily and judicious use of SFINAE can do the rest), but I don't have time to post a complete answer right now. Will do so if there isn't one when I get time later.

Comment: Be aware that your `Derived` can't cope with initializer lists. The only solution that works with them is inherited ctors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++11 offers [this as a feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement). Yet not even GCC actually implements it yet.

When it is actually implemented, it would look like this:

```
template<typename T> class Derived : Base<T>
{
    using Base<T>::Base;
};
```

That being said, it may not help for your case. Inherited constructors are an all-or-nothing proposition. You get *all* of the base class constructors, using exactly their parameters. Plus, if you define a constructor with the same signature as an inherited one, you get a compile error.

Answer (score 2):

To detect implicit/explicit constructibility for SFINAE:

```
template<class T0, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_convertible<const T0 &, Base<T>>::value, int>::type = 0>
    Derived(const T0& rhs) : Base<T>(rhs) { }
template<class T0, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_constructible<Base<T>, const T0 &>::value
    && !std::is_convertible<const T0 &, Base<T>>::value, int>::type = 0>
    explicit Derived(const T0& rhs) : Base<T>(rhs) { }
```

Use the fact that `std::is_convertible` checks *implicit* convertibility and use `std::is_constructible` to check explicit convertibility in addition.

Edit: fixed `enable_if` template parameters using solution from [boost::enable_if not in function signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743159/boostenable-if-not-in-function-signature).

Checks:

```
Derived<int>{5};                            // allowed
[](Derived<int>){}(5);                      // allowed
Derived<int>{std::string{"hello"}};         // allowed
[](Derived<int>){}(std::string{"hello"});   // not allowed
```

Comment: The `explicit` constructor can have its constraint expressed in terms of `std::is_constructible<Base<T>, T0 const&>::value && !std::is_convertible<T0 const&, Base<T>>::value`. (You also want to fix the first constraint: if the parameter is `T0 const&`, then that's what you want to check against with `std::is_convertible`, not `T0`.)