# Class template: why can't I specialize a single method for void type?

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I have a class template:

```
template <typename Argument> class Signal
{
    void invoke(Argument arg) {}
};
```

Now I want to invoke signals without parameter (meaning `void` parameter). I assume I could specialize the whole class for `void` and it would compile. But there's a lot of code in the class, I don't want to duplicate it. I want to only specialize whatever neccessary. So I try adding:

```
// void specialization
template<> 
void Signal<void>::invoke()
{

}
```

And get an error:

> error C2244: 'Signal::invoke' : unable to match function
>   definition to an existing declaration

Why is that?

The same code works for any type other than `void`.

Comment: What is "void parameter"? `void*` ok, but `void`? What is expected by, for example, `void x;`? A function `void f( void );` is the same as `void f()`, does not take any parameters.

Comment: @KirilKirov: that is expected to be a compilation error. But I don't instantiate objects of type `Argument`.

Comment: Buy you _do_ specialize for this type, so the compiler can check if it's ok or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specialization for this template:

```
template <typename Argument> class Signal
{
    void invoke(Argument arg) {}
};
```

would be:

```
template<> 
void Signal<void>::invoke(void arg)
{

}
```

which is illegal because you can't have a void object.

One way of doing what you want is to use overloading to declare both invoke methods, and use some templating tricks (I believe this one is called [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)) to only allow the correct overload available based on your class template argument:

```
template <typename Argument> class Signal
{
public:
    static constexpr bool IsVoid = is_same<Argument, void>::value;

    template <typename T = Argument, typename = typename std::enable_if< !IsVoid && is_same<Argument, T>::value>::type >
    void invoke(T arg) {
        // only available for non-void types
    }

    template <typename T = Argument, typename = typename std::enable_if< IsVoid >::type >
    void invoke() {
        // only available for void class specialization
    }
}


Signal<void> sv;
Signal<int> si;

sv.invoke(); // OK
si.invoke(1); // OK

sv.invoke(1); // NOT OK
sv.invoke("s"); // NOT OK
si.invoke(); // NOT OK
si.invoke("s"); // NOT OK
```

You can find more about the usage of `enable_if` here: [std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function), [Why should I avoid std::enable_if in function signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600201/why-to-avoid-stdenable-if-in-function-signatures).

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting, I didn't know of this trick nor of `std::enable_if`.

Comment: Glad you like it. I'm not an expert on SFINAE by any means, so if anyone feels like improving this, go ahead! (For instance: I couldn't find a way to do it without introducing an intermediate template type)

Answer (score 1):

What about C++11 variadic templates :

```
template<typename ...Args>
struct Signal {

typedef std::function<void(Args...)> slot_type;

std::list<slot_type> listeners;

template<typename Callable>
void connect(Callable callable) {
    listeners.emplace_back(callable);
}

void invoke(Args... args) {
    for(slot_type& slot : listeners)
        slot(args...);
}

};

void show_me(const std::string& data, int id) {
    std::cout << "hello " << data << " : " << id << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Signal<std::string, int> s;
    s.connect(show_me);
    s.invoke("world", 42);
    // ...
}
```

It scales well with 0, 1 or more args.

Comment: Interesting! is that a working signal/slot implementation in 10 lines? Very cool, I should rewrite my classes once C++ 11 is available to me.

Answer (score 0):

If yo will try to declare a variable

```
void a;
```

you also will receive a compile error.

The problem is that compiler expects some type instead of Argument here

```
template <typename Argument> class Signal
{
    void invoke(Argument arg) {}
};
```

and void is not treated as a type here.