# std::enable_if as single argument of constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, enable-if

I'm fairly new to template metaprogramming and have been working through some of the concepts - however, I've been stumped a little by this particular snippet I came across.

```
template<class TAG, typename... DATATYPES>
struct Message {

    Message (typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(DATATYPES) >= 1>) {
    }

    ... (various other constructor declarations here)

    std::tuple<DATATYPES...> m_data;
};
```

I had assumed when reading it that it was enabling the default constructor if there were one or more DATATYPES arguments, but having tested it all I got was a compilation error.

I would appreciate any assistance in helping my understanding of this snippet as I understand what enable_if is supposed to be doing but within this context I don't seem to be able to wrap my head around what's actually happening.

**EDIT:** I guess this is less a question of 'how do I achieve this particular effect?' and more along the lines of 'what is this code actually producing, and does it match up with what I understood to be the intention of the original author?'

Comment: I don't have the time to post a complete solution, but have a look at the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901637/class-template-why-cant-i-specialize-a-single-method-for-void-type/21904225#21904225, the same techniques can be applied to your problem, except that instead of using `IsVoid`, you would define something based on the number of arg types.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you see `enable_if` in a function that is not a template in its own right (i.e. members of class templates don't count), it's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::enable_if` is not used correctly if not followed by `::type`.  `std::enable_if<expr>` itself is a fairly useless `struct` type.

A correct way of conditionally enabling the default constructor:

```
template<class TAG, typename... DATATYPES>
struct Message {
private:
    struct dummy_type {};
public:
    template <typename T = std::tuple<DATATYPES...>>
    Message(
        typename std::enable_if<std::tuple_size<T>() >= 1, dummy_type>::type
        = dummy_type{}
    ) {}
    //...
};
```

[Live at coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4b64c6e895b09d0)

Comment: It will not work, unfortunately. The constructor itself needs to be a template.

Comment: Is what it's doing at the moment is creating a (useless) constructor with a struct arg if the enable_if condition evaluates to true?

Comment: Got it fixed now.  The original code is creating a useless constructor with struct arg no matter how many arguments there are.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm guessing that the original author didn't intend for that to be the case. Since this is a snippet from a framework that is intended to be made public I'll try to let the author know.

Answer (score 1):

Member function signatures are a part of class definition and need to be resolved when the class is instantiated. This means that compiler tries `enable_if`, too, and if the conditon is not fullfilled, it discovers that it doesn't have the nested `type` - hard error.

To make SFINAE work, you need to make the constructor a template and have `enable_if` depend on a template parameter. See @acheplers's answer for example.

What the code in OP does is a weird way of asserting the size of `DATATYPE` pack, which would be done with `static_assert` much more clearly. Or, maybe the author just didn't know how to do SFINAE correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your insights, much appreciated. I had a gut feeling that the code wasn't doing what was intended of it but I lack the firm grasp on the concepts to be able to tell for sure.