# Convert class<T> to class<U> if T is convertible to U

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, implicit-conversion, sfinae

I would like to create a templated class `test<T>` which I can convert into `test<U>` (possibly implicitly) if `T` is convertible to `U`. The simplest idea that came to my mind is to add a templated constructor that takes a `test<U>`, where the template argument `U` is controlled by `enable_if`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class test {
    int _foo;
public:
    int foo() const { return _foo; }

    test() : _foo(5) {}

    // This works:

    // template <typename U>
    // test(test<U> other)
    // : _foo(other.foo()) {}

    // This doesn't, can't resolve `U`:

    template <typename U>
    test(test<typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value, U>::type> other)
    : _foo(other.foo()) {}

};

int main() {
    test<int> a;
    test<long> b = a; // T = long, U = int

    // true
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_convertible<int, long>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I just declare the first templated constructor, the code works fine. With the second constructor, it doesn't compile:

```
21:9: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'U'
    test(test<typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value, U>::type> other)
    ^
```

**Why can't the compiler infer `U` in this case?** It looks quite straightforward, I must be missing something in the template deduction. Also, if the conversion cannot be achieved in this way, **what would be the best way of making `test<T>` convertible into `test<U>`?**

---

As a side note, I managed to get it to work by making all `test<T>` friends, and declaring a conversion operator which uses `enable_if` in the implementation (as follows), but I still would like to know why the first, simpler approach is not working.

```
template <typename T>
class test {
    int _foo;

    template <typename U>
    friend class test;

    test(int foo) : _foo(foo) {}

public:
    int foo() const { return _foo; }

    test() : _foo(5) {}

    template <typename U>
    operator test<U>() const {
        using return_t = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value, U>::type;
        return test<return_t>(_foo);
    }
};
```

Comment: Somewhat relevant: [Why should I avoid std::enable_if in function signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600201/why-should-i-avoid-stdenable-if-in-function-signatures), _"Put the hack in the template parameters"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't the compiler infer U in this case?

Type deduction fundamentally cannot infer `T` from parameter types such as `a<T>::b`. Even if you have

```
template <typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };
```

then the compiler *still* cannot rule out you providing a specialisation somewhere that sneakily makes `identity<X>::type` `Y` for some type `X`.

It's the same with `std::enable_if`: standard library class templates don't get special treatment in the language rules, so the compiler cannot figure out that if `std::enable_if<cond, U>::type` is supposed to be `X`, then `U` has to be `X`.

This is why for regular functions, `std::enable_if` typically appears in the return type. It can't be in the parameters, for the same reason as for constructors. It can't be in a template parameter, as the caller could specify a different type and bypass your restriction. But the return type is safe.

Constructors don't have a return type. Luckily though, callers cannot explicitly specify constructor template arguments, so putting `std::enable_if` in a template default argument as already answered by  m.s. is safe there.

Answer (score 3):

`U` appears in a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context).

This solves the compiler error:

```
template <typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value, U>::type>
test(test<U> other)
: _foo(other.foo()) {}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bca7d781c1023243)</kbd>