# constructor overloading and SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++14, enable-if

As an exercise in understanding the usage of `std::enable_if` I tried implementing a wrapper class (struct) to represent a particular type at any given point in time:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<typeinfo>
#include<iostream>
using std::enable_if;
using std::is_same;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T>
struct type_wrap{

                 type_wrap(typename enable_if<is_same<int,T>::value,T>::type&& rrT):value(rrT){
                         cout << "The wrapped type is " << typeid(value).name() << endl;
                         cout << "The wrapped value is " << value << endl;
                } 
                 type_wrap(typename enable_if<is_same<float,T>::value,T>::type && rrT):value(rrT){
                         cout << "The wrapped type is " << typeid(value).name() << endl;
                         cout << "The wrapped value is " << value << endl;
                 }

                 T& value;
};

int main(){

        type_wrap<int>(0);
        type_wrap<float>(0.5);
        return(0);
}
```

The above code does not compile:

```
so_main.cpp:16:47: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::enable_if<false, int>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
                 type_wrap(typename enable_if<is_same<float,T>::value,T>::type && rrT):value(rrT){
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
so_main.cpp:26:9: note: in instantiation of template class 'type_wrap<int>' requested here
        type_wrap<int>(0);
        ^
so_main.cpp:12:47: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::enable_if<false, float>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
                 type_wrap(typename enable_if<is_same<int,T>::value,T>::type&& rrT):value(rrT){
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
so_main.cpp:27:9: note: in instantiation of template class 'type_wrap<float>' requested here
        type_wrap<float>(0.5);
        ^
2 errors generated.
```

The code works if I were to remove one of the overloaded constructors, and the corresponding instantiation from `main()`. But that defeats the whole purpose of this exercise.

Can someone point out the cause for the compilation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFINAE works on template method(/constructor), here it is your class which is template, you might use the following (even if specialization seems simpler/better in your case):

```
template<typename T>
struct type_wrap{
    template <typename U,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, U>::value
                               && is_same<int, T>::value>* = nullptr>
    type_wrap(U arg) : value(arg){
        // Int case
        std::cout << "The wrapped type is " << typeid(value).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The wrapped value is " << value << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename U,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<float, U>::value
                               && is_same<float, T>::value>* = nullptr>
    type_wrap(U arg) : value(arg){
        // float case
        std::cout << "The wrapped type is " << typeid(value).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The wrapped value is " << value << std::endl;
    }
    T value;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9da1683beadc99e)

Comment: @user9196120: Typo fixed, Demo added.

Comment: As you may notice, `type_wrap<float>(0.5)` is invalid with my version as you pass `double` instead of `float`. Whereas specialization create non template methods which allow conversion/promotion.

Comment: @@Jarod421 Could you provide an explanation. about why you use * for enable_if_t and set it to nullptr? I am curious about the logic involved, and not sure I understand it.

Comment: You might look at [why-should-i-avoid-stdenable-if-in-function-signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600201/why-should-i-avoid-stdenable-if-in-function-signatures) which show the different way to use `std::enable_if`.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone point out the cause for the compilation error?

Because `std::enable_if` will make one of your constructors illegal depending on each:

```
type_wrap<int>(0);
type_wrap<float>(0.5);
```

`int` or `double` will force the other side of `std::is_same` to have `false`, [in which case `std::enable_if` has no `type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {}; // int or float will get this on each constructor.

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

Instead, use template specialization as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct type_wrap;

template<>
struct type_wrap<float>
{
    type_wrap(float&& rrT) :value(rrT) {
        cout << "The wrapped type is " << typeid(value).name() << endl;
        cout << "The wrapped value is " << value << endl;
    }

    float& value;
};

template<>
struct type_wrap<int>
{
    type_wrap(int&& rrT) :value(rrT) {
        cout << "The wrapped type is " << typeid(value).name() << endl;
        cout << "The wrapped value is " << value << endl;
    }

    int& value;
};
```

If your compiler supports C++17, `if constexpr` makes this a lot easier and more straight-forward:

```
template<typename T>
struct type_wrap
{
    type_wrap(T&& rrT):value(rrT)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same<int, T>::value)
        {
            cout << "The wrapped type is " << typeid(value).name() << endl;
            cout << "The wrapped value is " << value << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The wrapped type is " << typeid(value).name() << endl;
            cout << "The wrapped value is " << value << endl;
        }
    } 

    T& value;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I don't quite get it. My understanding was the purpose of using enable_if() is to enable only one overload based on the particular instantiation. Your observation "int or double will counter the other side of std::is_same to have false," is not clear to me. I get a similar error even if I were to use only one instantiation, i.e., either int or float, in main().

Comment: @user9196120 The first constructor is illegal if `T` is `float`. The second constructor is illegal if `T` is `int`. There's no SFINAE in this case - your compiler must see two constructors valid in both cases.