# ambiguos call with SFINAE and default template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I have a code that should implement SFINAE to resolve between two different methods, which however have a different template signature: one has an additional non-type template parameter.
As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623831/8769985), for example, one should better implement the SFINAE in the template parameters.

The compiler however issues an "ambiguous call" error.

This (simplified) example illustrates the issue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <bool X>
class A {
   template <unsigned int I>
   void print_true_impl();
   
   void print_false_impl();

public:
   template <unsigned int I, bool activate = X, class = std::enable_if_t<activate>>
   void print() { print_true_impl<I>(); }
   
   template <bool activate = !X, class = std::enable_if_t<activate>>
   void print() { print_false_impl(); }
};

template <bool X>
template <unsigned int I>
void A<X>::print_true_impl()
{
    std::cout << "true " << I << std::endl;
}

template <bool X>
void A<X>::print_false_impl()
{
    std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  A<true> atrue;
  A<false> afalse;

  afalse.print();
  atrue.print<1>();
  return 0;
}
```

Check it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bc04e7e64c33e6a).

The compile error appears on

```
atrue.print<1>();
```

The reason for ambiguity lies in the fact that the template parameter `<1>` is implicitly converted to bool, hence the compiler can pick up the overload

```
template <bool activate = !X, class = std::enable_if_t<activate>>
   void print() { print_false_impl(); }
```

setting `activate = true`, and ignoring the default `activate = !X` (`=false` when called from `atrue`).

Ideally one would like to avoid the implicit conversions in the template parameters, such that `bool activate` is always set to the default value.

So, one way to solve the ambiguity would be to prepend the templates with a class to which an unsigned int cannot converted to. For example

```
   template <unsigned int I, class = A, bool activate = X, class = std::enable_if_t<activate>>
   void print() { print_true_impl<I>(); }
   
   template <class = A, bool activate = !X, class = std::enable_if_t<activate>>
   void print() { print_false_impl(); }
```

This works, however it seems inelegant to artificially add a useless template parameter.

Another alternative would be to pack the choice of overload inside a single method using `if-constexpr`, like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template <auto...>
inline constexpr bool dependent_false_v = false;

template <bool X>
class A {
   template <unsigned int I>
   void print_true_impl();
   
   void print_false_impl();

public:

    template <unsigned int... I>
    void print() {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(I) == 0) {
            print_false_impl();
        }
        else if constexpr (sizeof...(I) == 1) {
            print_true_impl<I...>();
        }
        else {
            static_assert(dependent_false_v<I...>, "Cannot call print()!");
        }
    }
};
```

Is there a better solution, *within c++17* (no concepts), and using SFINAE and not if-constexpr?

Comment: With given example, full specialization :) `A<true>`/`A<false>`.

Comment: Do you really need SFINAE friendly here? `static_assert` might be sufficient.

Comment: Interface seems strange BTW, IMO.

Comment: @Jarod42 This is of course a simplified example, in the real code I cannot full specialized because I have >1 template parameters in A. ```static_assert```: uhm, you're right I think. Removed ```activate``` and ```std::enable_if```, the two overload would be no longer ambiguous and a static_assert would prevent, say, ```A<true>::print()```. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: It is what I have in mind.

Comment: @Jarod42 OK, this is indeed a solution that suits my case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you could also declare `enum class eActivated: bool {kFalse = false, kTrue = true};` and use it as template parameter instead of `bool activate = X/!X`. Here is example: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fe45ae7c244d194